# No definition of [python-wxtools] for OS [osx]

Tags: python, macos, wxpython

I am getting this error:

> `actionlib: No definition of [python-wxtools] for OS [osx]`

when I run:

`rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro kinetic -y`.

I did `brew install wxpython`, but it didn't help.

I would appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: add `--skip-keys python-wxtools` to your command.

Comment: `--skip-keys python-wxtools` and `--skip-keys google-mock` is obviously required in Mojave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this error by doing:

```
sudo pip install -U wxpython
```